# SOLVED. Mock service.insert() works with ArgumentMatchers.any() only, triggers exception otherwise

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, exception, service, mockito

Im creating a test class using Mockito and everything is runnig OK, except by one mock that calls a service layer method and it only works if the input parameter is any() and it throws the following exception if the input parameter is native from the method.

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.devsuperior.dscatalog.dto.ProductDTO.getId()" because "productDTO" is null at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)`

Lets go through the code:
The service layer method, productDTO is a DTO class from a ordinary Product entity.

```java
    @Transactional
    public ProductDTO insert(ProductDTO productDTO) {
        Product entity = new Product();
        copyDtoToEntity(productDTO, entity);
        entity = repository.save(entity); // reposity.save() returns a reference to object saved in DB
        return new ProductDTO(entity);
    }
```

the controller layer method:

```java
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ProductDTO> insert(@RequestBody ProductDTO productDTO){
        productDTO = service.insert(productDTO); //[1]
        URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(productDTO.getId()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).body(productDTO);
        
    }
```

Before I continue I ran in debug mode this code and the ProdutDTO was correctly instanciated until the mock captured the `service.insert(productDTO)` call  and after this line [1] **productDTO = null**

my test class:

```java
@WebMvcTest(ProductResource.class)
public class ProductResourceTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProductService service;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private PageImpl<ProductDTO> page;
    private ProductDTO productDTO;
    private long existingId;
    private long nonExistingId;
    private long dependentId;
    private long productBadCategoryId;
    private String jsonBody;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {

        productDTO = Factory.createProductDTO();

        existingId = Factory.getExistingProductId();
        nonExistingId = 100L;
        dependentId = 50L;
        productBadCategoryId = 200L;

        page = new PageImpl<>(List.of(productDTO));

        when(service.findAllPaged(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(page);

        when(service.findById(existingId)).thenReturn(productDTO);
        when(service.findById(nonExistingId)).thenThrow(ResourceNotFoundException.class);

        when(service.update(eq(existingId), any())).thenReturn(productDTO);

        when(service.update(eq(nonExistingId), any())).thenThrow(ResourceNotFoundException.class);
        when(service.update(eq(productBadCategoryId), any())).thenThrow(NestedResourceNotFoundException.class);

        doNothing().when(service).delete(existingId);
        doThrow(ResourceNotFoundException.class).when(service).delete(nonExistingId);
        doThrow(DatabaseException.class).when(service).delete(dependentId);

        when(service.insert(any(ProductDTO.class))).thenReturn(productDTO); // IT WORKS! [2]  
        //when(service.insert( productDTO )).thenReturn(productDTO); // IT IT DOESNT WORKS!  [3] 

        jsonBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(productDTO);

    }
```

and finally the test method where the mock call triggers the exception

```
@Test
public void insertShouldReturnProductDTOCreated() throws Exception {

    ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(post("/products").content(jsonBody)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    result.andExpect(status().isCreated());
    result.andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").exists());
    result.andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").exists());
    result.andExpect(jsonPath("$.description").exists());
}
```

Whenever I uncomment line [3] and comment line [2] the exception above is rised.
Of course I could let this way (its working), but If I want to raise an exception for the case the object to be inserted has some issue,I could build a new service.insert() mock to test the throw of the exception. As it is I can´t because I cant diferentiate a any() object from another one.I have read some similar problems like mine and the proposed solution was to add @Autowired annotation with `service` variable, but in my case still the issue remains.

**The solution and a tentative of explanation what was happening:**

*Override HashCode/Equals methods in ProducDTO class.*

When serializing ProductDTO class (this line-> `jsonBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(productDTO)` ) and upon reception on resource layer it turns again into an object but its new reference  address it is not the same and for instance the non override equals will fail (it compares the reference address and not their content).

Comment: Most likely you have not overriden equals in ProductDTO, have you?

Comment: I got it now @Lesiak. No I did not, I did in the entity class (Product) but not in the DTO class. Thanks for the hint will try it